# Xamarin List View SelectedItem ViewModel binding

Tags: c#, xamarin

Using Visual Studio 2015 proff,

**My LoginViewModel Class (Portable Class Library)**

```
public class LoginViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyCollectionChanged
{
    LoginPage page;
    private ObservableCollection<Employees> _employeeList;
    private string _loginName;

    public ObservableCollection<Employees> EmployeeList
    {
        get { return _employeeList; }
        set
        {
            _employeeList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset);
        }
    }

    public string LoginName
    {
        get { return _loginName; }
        set
        {
            _loginName = value;
            if (_loginName != null)
            {
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public LoginViewModel(LoginPage parent)
    {
        page = parent;
    }

    public async void GetEmployees()
    {
        var loginService = new LoginService();
        EmployeeList = await loginService.GetEmployeesAsync();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
    protected virtual void OnCollectionChanged( NotifyCollectionChangedAction action)
    {
        CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(action));
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    }
}
```

**My LoginPage.xaml (Portable Class Library)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="ScannerApp.Views.LoginPage"
         xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:ScannerApp.ViewModels;assembly=ScannerApp">
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">

<Label Text="Please Login"
        VerticalOptions="Start"
        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
        IsVisible="true"
        FontSize="Large"
        FontAttributes="Bold" />

<ListView x:Name="mylist" ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeList}"
        HasUnevenRows="True" SelectedItem="{Binding LoginName}">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="12,6">
          <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </StackLayout>
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**My LoginPage.xaml.cs Class (Portable Class Library)**

```
public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
{
    public LoginPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new LoginViewModel(this);
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        LoginViewModel model = new LoginViewModel(this);
        model.GetEmployees();
        BindingContext = model;
    }

    public ListView MyList
    {
        get
        {
            return mylist;
        }
    }
}
```

**Question**

I get a list of employees, the list on the front end renders this.  The user then Selects a name from the list, At this point I would like to detect this and then navigate to my different page.
Currently my property is not hit, I'm wondering if this has anything to do with my Binding on the code behind "OnAppearing"? but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While what you have may work there are a few tweaks I would suggest.

No need to set your `BindingContext` in your constructor and in `OnAppearing()`. Just make your `LoginViewModel` a class level private property in your code-behind and only assign it to your `BindingContext` in your constructor. Then call `GetEmployees()` in `OnAppearing()`.

Also, you should make `GetEmployees()` return a `Task`, in order to await as far up the chain as possible.

ViewModel:

```
....

public async Task GetEmployees()
    {
        var loginService = new LoginService();
        EmployeeList = await loginService.GetEmployeesAsync();
    }

....
```

Code-behind:

```
public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
{
    private LoginViewModel _model;

    public LoginPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = _model = new LoginViewModel(this);
    }

    protected override async void OnAppearing() //Notice I changed this to async and can now await the GetEmployees() call
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        await _model.GetEmployees();
    }

    public ListView MyList
    {
        get
        {
            return mylist;
        }
    }

    private async void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e) {
        if (e.SelectedItem == null) return; 

        await Navigation.PushAsync(new MenuPage());
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<!-- Adding OnItemSelected in XAML below -->
<ListView x:Name="mylist"
          ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeList}"
          HasUnevenRows="True"
          SelectedItem="{Binding LoginName}"
          ItemSelected="OnItemSelected">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="12,6">
          <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </StackLayout>
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: thanks alot for the code clean up, ill give it a test after the weekend

Answer (score 1):

```
mylist.ItemSelected += async (sender, e) => {

            if (e.SelectedItem == null) return; 

            await Navigation.PushAsync(new MenuPage());
};
```

This works, had to set the page to a nav wrap in the App.cs, then apply this event handler to the OnAppearing method.